# Auto hide bottomNavigationViewEx while sliding the fragment

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I am new to programming I am creating a app based on the BottomNavigationView and the BottomNavigation I am using is the BottomNavigationViewEx. I want to hide it automatically when the user slides down or up. And again show it as he scrolls in the opposite direction.

This is my Java class where I have set OnItemSelectListener

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private Context mContext = Welcome.this;

    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
    private ChatsFragment chatsFragment;
    private PostsFragment postsFragment;
    private FavouritesFragment favouritesFragment;
    private ProfileFragment profileFragment;
    private Location lastLocation;

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private static final String TAG = "Welcome";
    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNav;
    private List<ListItems> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting");

        checkLocationPermission();

        setupBottomNavigationView();

        enableNavigation();

        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();

    }

    private void setupBottomNavigationView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting bottomnavigationview");
        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.nav_bottom);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setUpNavigationView(bottomNav);
    }

    private void enableNavigation() {
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.btnHome:
                        if (homeFragment == null) homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.btnChats:
                        if (chatsFragment == null) chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, chatsFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.btnPost:
                        if (postsFragment == null) postsFragment = new PostsFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        manager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, postsFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.btnFavourites:
                        if (favouritesFragment == null) favouritesFragment = new FavouritesFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager3 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        manager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, favouritesFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.btnProfile:
                        if (profileFragment == null) profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager4 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        manager4.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, profileFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.btnHome:
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnChats:
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnPost:
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnFavourites:
                        ;
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnProfile:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 98);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 98);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setInterval(15000000).setFastestInterval(10000000).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY).setSmallestDisplacement(0);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 98:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (checkPlayServices()) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                        createLocationRequest();
                    }
                }

        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
                addConnectionCallbacks(this).
                addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
                addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 97).show();
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This Device Is Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

This is my BottomNavigationViewEx Helper Class

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "BottomNavigationViewHel";

public static void setUpNavigationView(BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx){
    Log.d(TAG, "setUpNavigationView: setting BottomNavigation");
    bottomNavigationViewEx.enableAnimation(false);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.enableShiftingMode(false);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.setTextVisibility(false);

}

}
```

Any one having any experience doing so please help me!

Comment: use coordinator layout

Comment: No it didn't solve the problem. There was no change doing so!